# Google Calendar errors on importing .ics file

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

I'm having a hard time getting my subscription calendar to work with Google Calendar.  The following URL works correctly with Outlook and Apple Calendar (iCal), but I get an error from Google - "The address that you provided did not contain a calendar in a valid iCal or GData format."

My URL passes validation on the following validators (icalvalid.cloudapp.net/ and severinghaus.org/projects/icv/)

Can anyone provide any idea what is wrong?  Here is the URL:
https://beta.vcallboard.com/calls/exportcalendar.php?userID=Mg%3D%3D&token=MjB6N2E0OTk%3D

Theories I've already tried:
 - doesn't work over https - (I saved and uploaded the .ics file as a file in my server root and that URL worked - seems it has something to do with the auto-generation)
 - blank values for some fields aren't valid (it works if I upload it as a .ics file)

Comment: I added a '.' character after DESCRIPTION: and LOCATION: so they wouldn't be blank values.  Now Google will let me import the calendar but it won't actually show any events.

Comment: I also tried this solution: http://devnet.superoffice.com/Developer/Blog/google-calendar-ical-parser/  Did not work.

Comment: My first advice is go to: http://icalendar.org/validator.html and validate your file/content. It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't defining the timezone that you are referencing in the ICS file.  You have a number of lines as follows:

`DTSTART;TZID=America/Chicago:20140121T010000`

but to use these you need to define your timezone, for example:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-CALNAME:Test calendar
X-WR-TIMEZONE:Indian/Reunion
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Indian/Reunion
TZURL:http://tzurl.org/zoneinfo/Indian/Reunion
X-LIC-LOCATION:Indian/Reunion
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:+034152
TZOFFSETTO:+0400
TZNAME:RET
DTSTART:19110601T000000
RDATE:19110601T000000
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
...
```

A good place to obtain timezone definition files is [tzurl.org](http://tzurl.org/)

Comment: I had tried to go to Time Zones due to this URL http://devnet.superoffice.com/Developer/Blog/google-calendar-ical-parser/ - however it actually broke the calendar working in Outlook.  So I reverted back to before.  You can take another look.  Now I just put DTSTART/DTEND in GMT format.

Comment: The ICS you put above imports fine in to Google Calendar for me and the events show up.

Comment: Yes - that's what's got me stumped.  I can import that ICS just fine, but if I choose "Add by URL" and provide the URL referenced, it won't show the events (though the calendar doesn't actually error out)

Comment: Very important if you need to be accurate with time and timezones!
Useful tool: http://icalendar.org/validator.html

Answer (score 2):

I was baffled by my problem because I could manually import the .ics file that was output by my script and it was read by Google Calendar with no problem.  So i figured I didn't have a problem with the actual format of the iCal file - I figured it had to be a problem with the headers or some server config.  So I did a few experiments...

Long story short, I was able to get this to work on Google Calendar by doing the following:

1. Load up a variable with all the iCal data, pulling from the database, site constants etc.  Make sure to use `\r` and `\n` for better validation in the validators.

   ```
   $iCal = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r
   VERSION:2.0\r
   PRODID:-//VirtualCallboard//".SITENAME."//EN\r
   CALSCALE:GREGORIAN\r
   METHOD:PUBLISH\r";
   while ($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
   {
       // i do a bunch of stuff here to get variables ready for the output
       $iCal .= "BEGIN:VEVENT\r
   DTSTAMP:".gmdate("Ymd\THis\Z")."\r
   DTSTART:".date("Ymd\THis\Z", strtotime($r[tdstart]))."\r
   DTEND:'.date("Ymd\THis\Z",   strtotime($r[tdend]))."\r
   SUMMARY:$r[title]\r
   UID:$r[callid]@".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."\r
   DESCRIPTION:$r[notes].\r
   LOCATION:$r[location_name].\r
   STATUS:CONFIRMED\r
   END:VEVENT\r\n";
   }
   $iCal .= "END:VCALENDAR";
   ```
2. Escape the special characters (all I know right now are commas). And then (here's the secret) - **use file_put_contents to write the string in the iCal variable into a file with a .ics extension in a cache directory**.

   ```
   //escape special characters.
   $iCal = str_replace(",","\,",$iCal);

   //output to a file
   $filename = 'site/cache/'.date("YmdHis").'.ics';
   file_put_contents($filename,$iCal);
   ```
3. Call the headers:

   ```
   //set correct content-type-header
   header("Content-Type:text/calendar");
   header("Content-Disposition:inline;filename=my_ical.ics");
   ```
4. Use file_get_contents to read the .ics data back out of the file and output it to the browser.

   ```
   print file_get_contents($filename);
   ```
5. cleanup the .ics file I created in my cache directory.

   ```
   unlink($filename);
   exit;
   ```

For some reason, which I can't explain, this made the exact same file work in Google Calendar.  So this is compatible with Outlook, Google Calendar, and Apple Calendar.

Comment: By using HEREDOC syntax, your solution is not necessarily portable. iCal files should have `\r\n` (CR+LF) line endings. In your HEREDOC string you have `\r` plus whatever your OS is using. If you transfer your files over FTP to a different OS and allow your FTP software to modify line endings then it could break, depending on your OS.

Comment: Very helpful, if working with .net you can do something like this:


contenidoArchivoICS.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
contenidoArchivoICS.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");
contenidoArchivoICS.AppendLine("PRODID:-//COMPANY//APP NAME//ES");
contenidoArchivoICS.AppendLine("CALSCALE:GREGORIAN");
contenidoArchivoICS.AppendLine("METHOD:PUBLISH");

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth remembering that Google caches calendar URLs and only refreshes them every x hours (12?). So, if you tried adding your URL before you'd got it working correctly, it might still be showing that old version, which may be nothing.

Try adding an irrelevant change to your URL, eg, a query on the end (?foo=1), or change the address on the server if you can.

https://www.binarysludge.com/2012/02/01/how-to-force-refresh-google-calendar/

(Caching is a species of problem that never crossed my mind in the last hours of messing with headers and ics formatting. One tends to assume that one's changes are at least having an effect.)