# iCal format for Google Calendar / Yahoo calendar not working

Tags: php, calendar, timezone

I've created calendar file (.ics) output from my application for the purpose of consumption within a Calendar app such as Google Calendar. I've ran the below file through a validator, but it appears that neither Google nor Yahoo Calendars want to play ball. My Local Mac Calendar client works 100%. Can anyone see anything obvious about the file below that would potentially choke within Google Calendar? Or any additional fields they need? I get a 500 error back from Yahoo calendar too. Tearing hair out at this point.

I've tried with and without timezone information, and it doesn't seem to make much difference.

Header output

```
        header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT' ); 
        header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s' ) . ' GMT' ); 
        header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate' );
        header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false );
        header('Pragma: no-cache' );
        header('Content-type: text/calendar;');
        header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="calendar.ics"');
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Content-Length: " . strlen($generated));
```

UTC times or TZID I've experimented with and doesn't seem to make a difference. If anyone has a really simple example of a URL of .ics events that seems to work "cross calendar" would love to see it. Alternatively if someone can provide some decent libraries for this purpose that aren't a pain to integrate into a CakePHP project, that would suffice.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//MS//NONSGML//EN
X-WR-CALNAME:Holidays
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:1075
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/London:20150114T080000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/London:20150114T170000
DTSTAMP:20150114T080000Z
CREATED:20151019T211433Z
DESCRIPTION:Stat Holiday (1.0 days)
LAST-MODIFIED:20150114T080000Z
LOCATION:
SUMMARY: Statutory Day
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:1076
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/London:20150116T080000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/London:20150116T170000
DTSTAMP:20150116T080000Z
CREATED:20151019T211433Z
DESCRIPTION:Stat Holiday (1.0 days)
LAST-MODIFIED:20150116T080000Z
LOCATION:
SUMMARY: Statutory Day
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:1079
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/London:20151020T123000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/London:20151020T170000
DTSTAMP:20151020T123000Z
CREATED:20151019T211433Z
DESCRIPTION:Holiday Request (3.0 days) test
LAST-MODIFIED:20151020T123000Z
LOCATION:
SUMMARY:admin Leave
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:1080
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/London:20151021T080000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/London:20151021T123000
DTSTAMP:20151021T080000Z
CREATED:20151019T211433Z
DESCRIPTION:Holiday (3.0 days) test
LAST-MODIFIED:20151021T080000Z
LOCATION:
SUMMARY:admin Leave
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:1081
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/London:20151022T080000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/London:20151022T170000
DTSTAMP:20151022T080000Z
CREATED:20151019T211433Z
DESCRIPTION:Holiday Request (3.0 days) test
LAST-MODIFIED:20151022T080000Z
LOCATION:
SUMMARY:admin Leave
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:1082
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/London:20151023T080000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/London:20151023T170000
DTSTAMP:20151023T080000Z
CREATED:20151019T211433Z
DESCRIPTION:Holiday Request (3.0 days) test
LAST-MODIFIED:20151023T080000Z
LOCATION:
SUMMARY:admin Leave
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: How are you outputting the ics file from php, via echo?
I can import your calendar straight into google calender so the file is ok.

Comment: I don't know _how_ you're trying to load this, but using only the HTTP headers and the .ics file you provided I was able to [_Add by using a link_](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37100?hl=en) without problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a combination of answers at SO ([Google Calendar errors on importing .ics file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21275581/google-calendar-errors-on-importing-ics-file)) and some source code from https://gist.github.com/jakebellacera/635416

My working code tested in several tools is:

```
<?php

//test
//
$summary = "test";
$datestart=time();
$dateend = $datestart + 3600;
$address = "Amsterdam";
$description = "testing ical format";
$filename = "test.ics";

// Variables used in this script:
//   $summary     - text title of the event
//   $datestart   - the starting date (in seconds since unix epoch)
//   $dateend     - the ending date (in seconds since unix epoch)
//   $address     - the event's address
//   $uri         - the URL of the event (add http://)
//   $description - text description of the event
//   $filename    - the name of this file for saving (e.g. my-event-name.ics)
//
// Notes:
//  - the UID should be unique to the event, so in this case I'm just using
//    uniqid to create a uid, but you could do whatever you'd like.
//
//  - iCal requires a date format of "yyyymmddThhiissZ". The "T" and "Z"
//    characters are not placeholders, just plain ol' characters. The "T"
//    character acts as a delimeter between the date (yyyymmdd) and the time
//    (hhiiss), and the "Z" states that the date is in UTC time. Note that if
//    you don't want to use UTC time, you must prepend your date-time values
//    with a TZID property. See RFC 5545 section 3.3.5
//
//  - The Content-Disposition: attachment; header tells the browser to save/open
//    the file. The filename param sets the name of the file, so you could set
//    it as "my-event-name.ics" or something similar.
//
//  - Read up on RFC 5545, the iCalendar specification. There is a lot of helpful
//    info in there, such as formatting rules. There are also many more options
//    to set, including alarms, invitees, busy status, etc.
//
//      https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5545.txt
// 1. Set the correct headers for this file
header('Content-type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8');
header("Content-Disposition:inline;filename=".$filename);
// 2. Define helper functions
// Converts a unix timestamp to an ics-friendly format
// NOTE: "Z" means that this timestamp is a UTC timestamp. If you need
// to set a locale, remove the "\Z" and modify DTEND, DTSTAMP and DTSTART
// with TZID properties (see RFC 5545 section 3.3.5 for info)
//
// Also note that we are using "H" instead of "g" because iCalendar's Time format
// requires 24-hour time (see RFC 5545 section 3.3.12 for info).
function dateToCal($timestamp) {
  return date('Ymd\THis\Z', $timestamp);
}
// Escapes a string of characters
function escapeString($string) {
  return preg_replace('/([\,;])/','\\\$1', $string);
}
// 3. Echo out the ics file's contents
$iCal="BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r
VERSION:2.0\r
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN\r
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN\r
BEGIN:VEVENT\r
DTSTAMP:".dateToCal(time())."\r
DTSTART:".dateToCal($datestart)."\r
DTEND:".dateToCal($dateend)."\r
UID:".uniqid()."\r
LOCATION:".escapeString($address)."\r
DESCRIPTION:".escapeString($description)."\r
SUMMARY:".escapeString($summary)."\r
END:VEVENT\r
END:VCALENDAR";
file_put_contents($filename,$iCal);
print file_get_contents($filename);
unlink($filename);
exit;
?>
```

It seems important that the line endings are correct (so \r\n).

Comment: This works in Mac / Google calendars. Yahoo calendar it still borks on.

Answer (score 4):

Your file is correct, I have uploaded it to google calendars myself, so it should work, however if you aren't stopping the script after the file echo, for example:

```
    //somewhere else in the script
    echo "this will break the file";
    header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT' ); 
    header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s' ) . ' GMT' ); 
    header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate' );
    header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false );
    header('Pragma: no-cache' );
    header('Content-type: text/calendar;');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="calendar.ics"');
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: " . strlen($generated));
    echo $generated;
    exit;//or return 200 or whatever
    echo "this could break the file except there is an exit;";//for example.
```

You could be in essence sending a malformed file.

Comment: good spot, how about `::foobar::` or `;;foobar;;`.. or possibly the same file again?

Comment: Interesting - for whatever reason, whatever I add: `echo "foobar";` or `echo "::foobar::";` doesn't even appear in the output provided. _**but**_ removing stuff from `$generated` actually removes it from the output. I have no idea what to think anymore. (i'm not using your example of exiting after outputting `$generated` either)

Comment: Im using a print 
print $generated; rather than an echo. Can't imagine that matters?

Comment: Add a die before you print and see if there is anything on the page, inspect with f12 if possible

Comment: If no output shows up, check the page source using `ctrl+u` or `f12`.

Answer (score 0):

In `.ics` file I added one line

```
METHOD:REQUEST
```

and yahoo started to work.
In my case I sended mails to hotmail, gmail and yahoo with `.ics` file and  yahoo didn't work without that line.
With

```
METHOD:PUBLISH
```

yahoo also dosn't work