# Google Calendar not showing events from iCalendar (ics) file hosted on S3

Tags: import, icalendar, gcal

I have generated an ICAL calendar and hosting it on Amazon S3:

- http://static.exyll.net/exports/chauffeur-ts.ics

When creating a new calendar and selecting import from file and use this ICAL file all events are imported but if I add an internet calendar the calendar gets added but events are never shown and the same for the calendar name.

This is the VCALENDAR data:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
PRODID:-//github.com/rianjs/ical.net//NONSGML ical.net 4.0//EN
VERSION:2.0
X-ORIGINAL-URL:http://static.exyll.net/exports/chauffeur-ts.ics
X-WR-CALNAME:VG Hoogvliet - chauffeur-ts
X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/Amsterdam
```

I tried different ways of formatting the VEVENT structures:

#### UTC timestamp

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20190114T080000Z
DTSTAMP:20190408T165745Z
DTSTART:20190114T060000Z
LOCATION:Rietbroek\, Hoogvliet
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:Onderbezetting - chauffeur-ts (07:00 - 2u)
UID:bed8e415ca443a72a67ea9dc0a6a9bc5
END:VEVENT
```

#### Local timestamp + TZID

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Amsterdam:20190114T080000
DTSTAMP:20190408T174500Z
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Amsterdam:20190114T060000
LOCATION:Rietbroek\, Hoogvliet
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:Onderbezetting - chauffeur-ts (06:00 - 2u)
UID:bed8e415ca443a72a67ea9dc0a6a9bc5
END:VEVENT
```

#### No location but with category

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
CATEGORIES:Onderbezetting
DTEND:20181206T080000Z
DTSTAMP:20190409T081553Z
DTSTART:20181206T050000Z
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:Onderbezetting - bevelvoerder (06:00 - 3u)
UID:638682f0542136a1884d6bdd7136b4c0
END:VEVENT
```

### HTTP headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: VMuHAsEtbQjjqiceomqVth61ycP8uuS7d73G7eI22NEv6EGDt/hAAl4EGA1nHJ4FGNopm+wahyw=
x-amz-request-id: DDD6997ACB409B12
Date: Mon, 08 Apr 2019 17:29:35 GMT
Cache-Control: public
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="calendar.ics"
Expires: Mon, 01 Apr 2019 00:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 08 Apr 2019 16:57:48 GMT
ETag: "a3e47ff07b8a9b17f91a4a7e4afb5325"
Content-Type: text/calendar
Content-Length: 2883
Server: AmazonS3
```

I've tried with different http cache headers, not using a content-disposition header, using timestamps without a Z, not specifying CALSCALE, METHOD, X-ORIGINAL-URL, or X-WR-TIMEZONE and I tried not using an UID or a new UID every time the file got generated.

I've reached my limit of finding what could potentially be wrong but still something is.

Who knows why this URL can be added in Google Calendar but never shows its events or its name?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21275581/google-calendar-errors-on-importing-ics-file/60613189#60613189 (Google caches calendar URLs)

Comment: @Andrew I'm familiar with cache busting but that wasn't my issue (see my own answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file contained an UTF8 BOM, this caused the following validator not to load. I'm using c# and had to use `new StreamWriter(s, new UTF8Encoding(false))` instead of `new StreamWriter(s, Encoding.UTF8)`

- http://ical-validator.herokuapp.com/urlvalidate?url=http://static.exyll.net/exports/bevelvoerder.ics

The validator states that the `ORGANIZER` property is needed but that is not correct.

Comment: I experienced the same. It occurs for any ics calendar containing a BOM, whether it is or NOT on Amazon S3. 
You are able to subscribe the calendar in Google Calendar but the events do NOT show up. 
Solution: remove the BOM, and the events show up.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some junk towards the end of the icalendar stream

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
CATEGORIES:Onderbezetting
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Amsterdam:20190412T190000
DTSTAMP:20190409T080434Z
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Amsterdam:20190412T150000
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:Onderbezetting - chauffeur-ts (15:00 - 4u)
UID:241e4276f83a3b1d91e6353059b9ee89
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
76f83a3b1d91e6353059b9ee89
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

(you have two END:VCALENDAR with stuff in between).

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. The corruption was due to me using `File.Open` instead of `File.Create`. Going to check if that resolves it.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to resolve the issue.